# How to create a table-view control

Tags: windows-phone-7

how to develop a scrolling table with rows which will have more than one dynamic data in one row ? It should take data from web browser.

Comment: Creating rows in table with dynamic data is quite simple but what do u mean by "It should take data from web browser."??

Comment: Thanks Amresh for your response.Taking data from web browser, I mean to say, I have a xaml page in my application, with a button.This will redirect to a web site and retrieve data from that site, for example list of items. And these list of items when clicked one by one should be displayed in home page in a row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the table like view as described by Matt Lacey. For dynamic data you can create data-template for your table and bind them to your data source. When you click items in a list you can modify ur data source so that it will be reflected in your table.
***Note:*** Make sure to implement INotifyPropertyChanged so the changes in your data are reflected correctly on the UI.

Answer (score 1):

To create a table, simply use a list where each item is a row in the grid and then template the item to display data inside a single row grid.

**IMPORTANT**: Be sure to set a fixed width on each cell so that all rows look the same and aren't resized independently.